# Spring-cleaning campaign on Pets.SE

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation, unanswered-questions, quality, event

I noticed that during the last year the quality of our site (according to the official quality metrics of StackExchange) deteriorated. You can have a look at our [current Beta status](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44686/pets).

[image: Pets beta status 2021-04-09]

We can't do much about the number of questions per day, but according to site statistics we have a steady influx of new users and visitors that didn't change for several years. But the number of unanswered questions increased from less than 5% (according to my memory) to now 10% and the average answers per question dropped below 2.

I'd like to invite all of our members to have a look around the list of [unanswered questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) and see if we can answer some of them. Maybe there has even been a similar question more recently, which might allow us to mark the old one as duplicate and clean it up.

**Let's see how much we can improve the statistic till the end of the month.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### We did it!

[image]

Within the 20 days of our campaign we were able to improve the number of answered question **and** the overall rating of Pets.SE.

- The percentage of answered questions increased from 90% to 91%, also increasing the rating from "okay" to "excellent". Considering the overall number of questions on this site, **this is a huge impact**.
- 32 answers were written by 10 different users - in addition to the usual answers to new questions.
- Funny coincidence: There was a total of 176 answers in April 2021 - exactly the same number as in April 2020. But in 2020 there were 105 questions compared to only 82 in 2021.

I'm extremely proud of anyone who decided to partake in this event, be it by writing an answer, spellchecking existing answers, leaving comments or even just voting. **Thank you!**

Comment: Yay! Well done, all of you!

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of new answers that were written during the spring-cleaning campaign that had at least one upvote or were accepted by the question owner. Any user could have added their answers to the list if they wanted. This was completely optional, but offered a way to draw attention to your answer and gain rewards in the form of upvotes and badges.

- [Are there any species of turtles that won't eat fish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31101/12501) - [Allerleirauh](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/14675/allerleirauh)
- [Glycemic load for foods with respect to dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31096/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [How to do an 8-hour road trip with a husky puppy?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31094/12501) - [Nai54](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/19872/nai54?tab=profile)
- [What are the health risk difference between elastration & surgical neuter?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31080/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Is fish pecking at other fish a sign of parasites?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31083) - [Pam](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12774/pam)
- [Female guppies are fine, but male is sick](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31082) - [Lila](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/17671/lila)
- [Can I help my kitten regrow fur after being affected with ear mites?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31103/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Do dogs need dog friends?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31104/19872) - [Nai54](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/19872/nai54)
- [Did “Rough Collie” dogs (and maybe other dogs?) actually guard the farm when all the humans were away?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31106/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Why is my cat losing hair in small patches on her head?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31114) - [Joseph Casey](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/20192/joseph-casey)
- [Why is my dog separating one pup and moving him?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31115/12501) - [Joseph Casey](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/20192/joseph-casey)
- [Do female bearded dragons menstruate?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31119/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Dog is newly aggressive towards other dogs after lockdown](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31123/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Protection of neighbours from dangerous dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31135/19872) - [Nai54](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/19872/nai54)
- [My dog is not eating her food](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31139) - [Joseph Casey](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/20192/joseph-casey)
- [My goldfish started growing a flower-like thing on his head and it is now disturbing it during eating](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31117) - [Joseph Casey](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/20192/joseph-casey)
- [Black spots at base of rat's whiskers](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31157/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Senior dog feeling down and shaking](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31169/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Over-excited, barking dog and ways to exercise or calm him](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31173/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Why did my dogs ears start to flop?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16466/why-did-my-dogs-ears-start-to-flop/31181#31181) - [Nai54](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/19872/nai54)
- [Are the snails suffering?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31218/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Kitten is cuddly, not playful--typical?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31219/16749) - [C.Koca](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16749/c-koca)
- [Cat is eating and drinking but hasn't gone to the bathroom since I got him a different kind of litter yesterday](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28906/cat-is-eating-and-drinking-but-hasnt-gone-to-the-bathroom-since-i-got-him-a-dif/31246#31246) - [SerenaT](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/14744/serenat)
- [Which dogs shed the least?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31237/19872) - [Nai54](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/19872/nai54)
- [Please help I found a strange sac on my cat's tail. What shall I do?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31262/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Do dogs and other intelligent animals (cows, etc.) blink to communicate?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31263/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Can dried Valerian root be used as a substitute for fresh root?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31266) - [Allison C](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/10702/allison-c)
- [Intact male started being aggressive with neutered dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31272/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [What OTC vitamins or supplements that people take are toxic to cats?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31273/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Introducing a deaf, almost completely blind elderly cat to our younger cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31270) - [bgse](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/19086/bgse)
- [Kitten stopped using litter tray after having had diarrhea](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31281/12501) - [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501/elmy)
- [Best methods to help your dog if he is scared of children?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17299/best-methods-to-help-your-dog-if-he-is-scared-of-children/31282#31282) - [Nai54](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/19872/nai54)